# python copy dictionary into excel

Tags: python

I have this dictionary:

dict1 = {"Name": 'Bob' , "Surname": 'red', "Age": 17 }

how can I copy the dictionary into an excel file?
I would like this output:

```
           Name       Surname          Age
           Bob        Red              17
```

thank you!

Comment: You can import a dictionary to a pandas DataFrame and then write the output to an Excel file, as long as you have OpenPyxl installed. You will need to adjust the structure of your input dict though -- I don't know if this is something that is possible for your use case. Side notes: you wouldn't be able to preserve the order of this dictionary structure you have specified without specifically storing the order separately as a dict is similar to a set (unordered). I would avoid using the Python keyword `dict` to name a variable.

Answer (score 2):

You can import a dictionary to a pandas DataFrame and then write the output to an Excel file, as long as you have OpenPyxl installed:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.DataFrame(dict1).to_excel('myfile.xlsx')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to guarantee the heading order (for versions of Python before 3.7), you'll need to specify it in a list. You can use the [`xlwt` library](https://github.com/python-excel/xlwt):

```
import xlwt
from datetime import datetime

wb = xlwt.Workbook()
ws = wb.add_sheet('My Sheet')

dict1 = {"Name": 'Bob' , "Surname": 'red', "Age": 17 }
headings = ['Name', 'Surname', 'Age']
for i,heading in enumerate(headings):
    ws.write(0, i, heading)
    ws.write(1, i, str(dict1[heading]))

wb.save('example.xls')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dict1 = {"Name": 'Bob' , "Surname": 'red', "Age": 17 }
```

You can save it in excel by saving it as pandas data frame in 2 different ways

## Long Format

#### Converting dictionary to pandas dataframe

```
df=pd.DataFrame(list(dict1.items())) #Python 3
df=pd.DataFrame(dict1.items()) #Python 2
```

this will store your data as :

```
         0    1
0     Name  Bob
1  Surname  red
2      Age   17
```

## Wide Format

#### Converting dictionary key as columns in pandas

```
df=pd.DataFrame(dict1, index=[0])
```

This will convert your data in the desired format

```
   Age Name Surname
0   17  Bob     red
```

And finally, you can save your data in excel

```
df.to_csv('myfile.csv', index =False)
```

Comment: If it was helpful, then please accept and upvote the answer. Thanks